# Create Trainable Tensorflow graph from frozen model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to create trainable tensorflow model from frozen model.

I have all weights and tensorflow layers from frozen model.

Using that I have created a new graph and initialize with those weights.

It looks ok.

But when I print all layer names, there are three names printed for each layer like

```
Mconv4_stage6_L2/biases
Mconv4_stage6_L2/biases/Assign
Mconv4_stage6_L2/biases/read
Mconv4_stage6_L2/weights
Mconv4_stage6_L2/weights/Assign
Mconv4_stage6_L2/weights/read
```

What are those Assign and read layers?

Initialization of weights and biases are as follows.

```
    def make_var(self, name, initializer=[], trainable=True):
       '''Creates a new TensorFlow variable.'''
       return tf.get_variable(name, trainable=self.trainable & trainable, initializer=initializer)

    @layer
    def conv(self,
             input,
             k_h,
             k_w,
             c_o,
             s_h,
             s_w,
             name,
             relu=True,
             padding=DEFAULT_PADDING,
             group=1,
             trainable=False,
             biased=True):
        # Verify that the padding is acceptable
        self.validate_padding(padding)
        # Get the number of channels in the input
        c_i = int(input.get_shape()[-1])
        # Verify that the grouping parameter is valid
        assert c_i % group == 0
        assert c_o % group == 0
        # Convolution for a given input and kernel
        convolve = lambda i, k: tf.nn.conv2d(i, k, [1, s_h, s_w, 1], padding=padding)
        with tf.variable_scope(name) as scope:
            for init_zer in self.inits_:
                if(init_zer['name'] == name+'/'+'weights' and 'conv' in init_zer['name']):
                    #print('weights '+init_zer['name'])
                    kernel = self.make_var('weights', initializer=tf.constant(init_zer['tensor']), trainable=self.trainable & trainable)#shape=[k_h, k_w, c_i / group, c_o]
            if group == 1:
                # This is the common-case. Convolve the input without any further complications.
                output = convolve(input, kernel)
            else:
                # Split the input into groups and then convolve each of them independently
                input_groups = tf.split(3, group, input)
                kernel_groups = tf.split(3, group, kernel)
                output_groups = [convolve(i, k) for i, k in zip(input_groups, kernel_groups)]
                # Concatenate the groups
                output = tf.concat(3, output_groups)
            # Add the biases
            if biased:
                for init_zer in self.inits_:
                    if(init_zer['name'] == name+'/'+'biases' and 'conv' in init_zer['name']):
                        #print('bias '+init_zer['name'])
                        biases = self.make_var('biases', initializer=tf.constant(init_zer['tensor']), trainable=self.trainable & trainable)
                output = tf.nn.bias_add(output, biases)

            if relu:
                # ReLU non-linearity
                output = tf.nn.relu(output, name=scope.name)
            return output
```

Do I need to run global_variables_initializer again in this case?
My whole codes are 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcoc1hsd3j2i0od/CMUNet.py?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kcmrm06k9dz40em/network_base.py?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2r164gdk2fzshhr/network_cmu.py?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is correct. What I did is upload the model and initialize the weights and biases. Then the model was saved. From the saved model and checkpoint, the new model is freezed. I made comparison at Tensorboard for old freezed model and new freezed model. They are same, I don't see any node with Assign and read. But I wonder what are they when I print node names.